# Pandas read_csv -- Unable to Parse String " FALSE"

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote some code to help me do data analysis on laboratory testing data using the standard combination of pandas, matplotlib, etc. I have recently added a solenoid valve to the setup, and my PLC is outputting a boolean value corresponding to the state of that valve.

However... my read_csv() function

```
    data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, working_dir, staticDataFileName), encoding_errors='ignore', false_values=[" FALSE", "  FALSE"])
```

is now bombing on that column, and I can't seem to find the write option to get it to work. As the title suggests, the value in the CSV actually has a space preceding the FALSE text. I've tried playing around encoding_errors and false_values options to no avail.

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string " False"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12956/1394488190.py in <module>
     13     #print("Reading static file #" + str(dataset+1) + " of " + str(len(working_dir)))
     14     print("Reading static file : " + staticDataFileName[dataset])
---> 15     temp = readRawData(working_dir[dataset], staticDataFileName[dataset], dataset)
     16     data = pd.concat([data,temp],ignore_index=True)
     17     if compute_dynamic_data:

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12956/153126867.py in readRawData(working_dir, staticDataFileName, dataSet_index)
     96     cols=[i for i in data.columns if i not in ["Time"]]
     97     for col in cols:
---> 98         data[col]=pd.to_numeric(data[col])
     99     data.drop_duplicates()
    100 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py in to_numeric(arg, errors, downcast)
    181         coerce_numeric = errors not in ("ignore", "raise")
    182         try:
--> 183             values, _ = lib.maybe_convert_numeric(
    184                 values, set(), coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric
    185             )

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string " False" at position 0
```

I have confirmed that this column with values of " FALSE" is causing the problem by removing the values from that column -- and it seems to work fine.

I feel like this should be a simple thing, but I sure am making it difficult.

Comment: Hey Mike! It seems to me that the code is trying to convert " False" to a numeric value according to what's written in `readRawData`. Is that indeed what you're intending to do with columns containing " False" ?

Comment: probably nothing. There is a chance I'll filter on it at some point... but I could just as easily filter assuming it's a string. How can I force it read as string and not try and convert?